# How to solve DSInit not found error in Microsoft Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

i've read some articles "http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/40e97e/windows-azu-creating-and-deploying-worker-role/"

if i try to run my code' error occurs:

ERROR: Windows Azure Tools: Failed to initialize the Development Storage service. Unable to start Development Storage

i made some investigation to solve this boring problem:

http://www.nimbo.com/blog/error-failed-to-initialize-windows-azure-storage-emulator/
http://kristofmattei.be/2010/01/28/windows-azure-sdk-connecting-to-non-sqlexpress-instance/

if i run "dsinit /sqlinstance:." if i use :"WAStorageEmulator init –forcecreate" result 's below:
Error: "DsInit can not found"[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Azure SDK 2.3, please note that **`DSInit.exe`** has been removed from the SDK. It has been replaced with **`WAStorageEmulator.exe`** which can be found in **`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\Storage Emulator`** folder.

To initialize storage emulator, the command you will use is:

```
WAStorageEmulator init -forcecreate
```

This is similar to `DSInit /forceCreate`.

There are some other options available as well:

```
WAStorageEmulator clear table
```

Removes just the tables from storage emulator.

```
WAStorageEmulator clear blob
```

Removes just the blob containers from storage emulator

```
WAStorageEmulator clear queue
```

Removes just the queues from storage emulator.

```
WAStorageEmulator clear all
```

Removes all tables, queues and blob containers without deleting the database.

I wrote a blog post about it as well where I talked in somewhat more details about this. You can read the blog post here: [`http://gauravmantri.com/2014/04/04/managing-storage-emulator-in-azure-sdk-version-2-3`](http://gauravmantri.com/2014/04/04/managing-storage-emulator-in-azure-sdk-version-2-3)

Comment: WAStorageEmulator init –forcecreate     IS NOT WORKED. ALSO  WAStorageEmulator init -server .\YUSUFK -sqlinstance .\SQLEXPRESS -forcecreate  IS NOT WORKED

Comment: i added inside of my question as a picture

Comment: This is really weird!!! When I copy the command from my answer above and paste it in command window, I get the exact error you're getting. However when I manually type the same command, it works. Can you try by manually typing in the command.

Comment: i dont know it is really boring situation!

Comment: WAStorageEmulator init 'H2014-008' 'MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER' –forcecreate   is not working

Comment: You would need to specify `-server` and `-sqlinstance` in the command. I don't see that above.

Comment: Windows Azure Tools: Failed to initialize Windows Azure storage emulator. Unable to open wait handle.

Comment: Man .... something is messed up on your machine :) ... can you try going with the default ... just use `WAStorageEmulator init –forcecreate` ... I guess it uses localDB or local SQL Express by default.

Comment: What do you say we start a new question? I'm afraid there're too many comments going on in this thread. Furthermore the problem you're facing now is not related to your original question.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue when the emulator wouldn't initialise with SQL SERVER installed (it looks for SQLEXPRESS by default). For Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator v5.8 the accepted answer no longer works. I found the solution on the [Microsoft site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator#initialize-the-storage-emulator-to-use-a-different-sql-database). In summary:

From the console window that opens on starting the emulator you can use the following commands:

If you want to initialise a specific SQL Server Instance

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /server <SQLServerInstance>
```

You can also use the following command, which directs the emulator to use the default SQL Server instance

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /server .
```

Or, you can use the following command, which reinitializes the database to the default LocalDB instance

```
AzureStorageEmulator.exe init /forceCreate
```